# spotify web api render only last playlist in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am making a Spotify clone using react.js with spotifyWebApi with the help of axios.I also use Context api with styled components in react.js

I want to fetch current user playlist in playlist.js which i mention below .It works and get the current user playlist but the problem is that it only renders the last playlist only.

here is the index.js

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <StateProvider  initialState={initialState} reducer={reducer} >
    <App />
    </StateProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

here is StateProvider.jsx

```
import {createContext,useContext,useReducer} from "react";

export const StateContext=createContext();

export const StateProvider=({children,initialState,reducer})=>(
  <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer,initialState)}>
   { children}
  </StateContext.Provider>
  )

export const useStateProvider=()=>useContext(StateContext);
```

here is spotify.js i only mention the function part

```
const[{token},dispatch]=useStateProvider();

  useEffect(()=>{
    const getUserInfo=async()=>{
    const {data}=await axios.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me",{
      headers:{
        Authorization:"Bearer "+token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    })
    const userInfo={
      userId:data.id,
      userName:data.display_name,
    }
    dispatch({type:reducerCases.SET_USER,userInfo})
    // console.log(userInfo);
    }
    getUserInfo();
  },[token,dispatch])
```

here is the Playlists.jsx

```
   function Playlists() {
        const [{token,playlists},dispatch] = useStateProvider();
     
        useEffect(()=>{
            const playListData=async()=>{
            const response=await axios.get(
                " https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists ",
                {
                    headers:{
                        Authorization:"Bearer "+token,
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    },
                }
            
            )
           
            const {items}=response.data;
            console.log(response,"heelo")
            const playlists=items.map(({name,id})=> {
                return{name,id}
            })
            dispatch({type:reducerCases.SET_PLAYLISTS,playlists})
            
            }
             playListData()
        }
            ,[token,dispatch])
     return (
    <Container>
        <ul>
            {playlists.map(({name,id})=>{
                return(
                    <li key={id}>{name}</li>
                )
            })}
           
        </ul>
```

Comment: Put the function "playListData" outside of the useEffect and inside the useEffect call that function, and in the [ ] of the useEffect put the function

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).